# Netty Exception not caught properly

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, netty

Hi guys I'm trying to build a search engine that searches ES for matches, the interface has a dynamic counter of hits that gets updated after each key press and I'm looking for a way to validate, workaround or catch an exception that gets thrown when the user searches using a double quote for example:

```
a >> 4500 hits
ab >> 1200 hits
ab" >> massive stack trace
ab"c"> 250 hits
```

The stack:

```
2013-04-02 16:41:42,703 [New I/O  worker #1] WARN  transport.netty  - [Jekyll] Exception caught on netty layer [[id: 0x0106148c, /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx => /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx]]
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 54
    at org.elasticsearch.common.Unicode.UTF8toUTF16(Unicode.java:190)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.Unicode.unsafeFromBytesAsUtf16(Unicode.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.Unicode.fromBytes(Unicode.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.Unicode.fromBytes(Unicode.java:73)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.count.CountRequest.toString(CountRequest.java:334)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.TransportBroadcastOperationAction$AsyncBroadcastAction.onOperation(TransportBroadcastOperationAction.java:306)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.TransportBroadcastOperationAction$AsyncBroadcastAction$3.handleException(TransportBroadcastOperationAction.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:287)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:278)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.process(MessageChannelHandler.java:230)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.callDecode(MessageChannelHandler.java:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:94)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:372)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:246)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:38)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-04-02 16:41:42,705 [New I/O  worker #2] WARN  transport.netty  - [Jekyll] Exception caught on netty layer [[id: 0x02474fc7, /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx => /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx]] ... etc
```

Any suggestions? Please ask if you need any additional information.

Try/Catch block that fails to catch the exception:

```
def query_str = buildQuery(params)
log.debug("count query: ${query_str}");
log.debug("enter try:");
try{      
  def search = esclient.count {
    indices "something"
    types "somethingelse"
    query {
      query_string (query: query_str)
    }
  }
}
catch ( Exception e ) {
  log.error("The Query is invalid!");
  result.hits = 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you send queries to elasticsearch?

Comment: added the try/catch block I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a bug that was fixed in v0.19.9. Starting with v0.19.9, elasticsearch should return more reasonable error messages.

Comment: I'll try to upgrade today, I was using v0.19.4 I'll see how that goes, if it goes well the tick is yours :) Thanks